# How to convert rows to columns in case of only two columns in a table?

Tags: sql-server

Table contains the following columns and data:

```
Id | Date

1  | 04/09/2014 13:00:00
1  | 04/10/2014 15:00:00
1  | 04/12/2014 16:00:00
1  | 04/13/2014 18:00:00
2  | 04/11/2014 13:00:00
2  | 04/12/2014 15:00:00
2  | 04/12/2014 16:00:00
```

I need to get every vertical pair for each Id and transform it into horizontal view, the result should look like:

```
Id | Date1               | Date2
1  | 04/09/2014 13:00:00   04/10/2014 15:00:00
1  | 04/12/2014 16:00:00   04/13/2014 18:00:00
2  | 04/11/2014 13:00:00   04/12/2014 15:00:00
2  | 04/12/2014 16:00:00   NULL
```

There is a null value since date is absence in a pair of Id = 2. There are no more columns in the table.

Comment: selft-join subselects with row-number(http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms186734.aspx) and some modulo stuff might be a way to go. let me know if that leads you to a solution. i will try to come up with the complete SQL if this does not help

Comment: with sql server 2008?

Comment: sql server 2012. which of sql should contain row_number both or subquery?

Comment: Please feedback on updated question. Thank you

Comment: You need to create a new questions, this interferes with peoples ability to guage what you need, and determine the right answer. It is also confusing to those that have answered already and have not been selected for an answer.

Answer (score 4):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82399/2)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table T
(
  Id int,
  Date datetime
)

go

insert into T values
(1  ,'04/09/2014 13:00:00'),
(1  ,'04/10/2014 15:00:00'),
(1  ,'04/12/2014 16:00:00'),
(1  ,'04/13/2014 18:00:00'),
(2  ,'04/11/2014 13:00:00'),
(2  ,'04/12/2014 15:00:00'),
(2  ,'04/12/2014 16:00:00')
```

**Query 1**:

```
select T.Id,
       min(T.Date) as Date1,
       case when count(*) = 2 then max(T.Date) end as Date2
from (
     select T.Id,
            T.Date,
            (1 + row_number() over(partition by T.Id order by T.Date)) / 2 as rn
     from T
     ) as T
group by T.Id, T.rn
order by T.Id, T.rn
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82399/2/0)**:

```
| ID |                        DATE1 |                        DATE2 |
|----|------------------------------|------------------------------|
|  1 | April, 09 2014 13:00:00+0000 | April, 10 2014 15:00:00+0000 |
|  1 | April, 12 2014 16:00:00+0000 | April, 13 2014 18:00:00+0000 |
|  2 | April, 11 2014 13:00:00+0000 | April, 12 2014 15:00:00+0000 |
|  2 | April, 12 2014 16:00:00+0000 |                       (null) |
```

Comment: Thank you, it works and hope it will work even with huge amount of data.

Comment: @user3580877 You shouldn't really change the question like that. What you have now does not at all resemble what you had to start with. I added a second answer that is as close as I can get your new requirements and I guessed on the input data. I also guessed the your expected output has some errors in it.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82399/7)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table T
(
  Id int,
  Date datetime
)

go

insert into T values
(1  ,'04/09/2014 13:00:00'),
(1  ,'04/10/2014 15:00:00'),
(1  ,'04/12/2014 16:00:00'),
(1  ,'04/13/2014 18:00:00'),
(2  ,'04/11/2014 13:00:00'),
(2  ,'04/12/2014 15:00:00'),
(2  ,'04/12/2014 16:00:00')
```

**Query 1**:

```
select T1.Id,
       T1.Date as Date1,
       T3.Date2
from T as T1
    outer apply (
                select top(1) T2.Date
                from T as T2
                where T1.Date < T2.Date and
                      T1.Id = T2.Id
                order by T2.Date
                ) as T3(Date2)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82399/7/0)**:

```
| ID |                        DATE1 |                        DATE2 |
|----|------------------------------|------------------------------|
|  1 | April, 09 2014 13:00:00+0000 | April, 10 2014 15:00:00+0000 |
|  1 | April, 10 2014 15:00:00+0000 | April, 12 2014 16:00:00+0000 |
|  1 | April, 12 2014 16:00:00+0000 | April, 13 2014 18:00:00+0000 |
|  1 | April, 13 2014 18:00:00+0000 |                       (null) |
|  2 | April, 11 2014 13:00:00+0000 | April, 12 2014 15:00:00+0000 |
|  2 | April, 12 2014 15:00:00+0000 | April, 12 2014 16:00:00+0000 |
|  2 | April, 12 2014 16:00:00+0000 |                       (null) |
```

Comment: sql gives an error 'lead' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @user3580877 Didn't you say that you used SQL Server 2012? What does `select @@version` give you?

Comment: I apologize for mistake it's Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: @user3580877 added a version that will work from SQL Server 2005 and up.

Comment: Thank you for solution. Is there any better optimized version for that select, since for two Ids it takes 1 second.

Comment: @user3580877 I would recommend an index then. For the table you have here it would be `create index IX_T on T(Id, Date)`

Comment: @user3580877 Your question has been rolled back. For future reference, create a new question if your requirements have changed.

Comment: Everything works fine. Thank you. Will create a new one after that.